# Date Check Amount of Time Passed

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to check if the user has been on the site longer then 6 months, if they have to prompt a message.

I cannot get this to work, it keeps thinking 6 weeks has passed even when the date is moved to today.

**Currently my code.**

```
            $created_at = "2014-12-01 16:58:23";

            $sixweek = 604800 * 6;

            if(strtotime($created_at) < time() + ($sixweek))
            {
                $data['needsnewimage'] = 1;
                die('6 Weeks has passed ');

            }else{
                $data['needsnewimage'] = 0;
                die('6 Weeks has not passed');
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not going to work. Consider this: someone signs up for your site TODAY:

```
$created_at = '2014-12-01 08:00:00'; // "today"

if ($created_at < $today + $sixweek) ...
```

becomes

```
if ($today < $today + $sixweek)
if (0 < $sixweek)
```

and will always be true.

You want

```
if ($created_at > (time() - $sixweek))
                ^---------^
```

Note the changed math

Comment: Missing a `)` on the last code piece: `($created_at > (time() - $sixweek)` --> `($created_at > (time() - $sixweek))` . Edit: He replaced it now :P

Comment: Tried this as still it shows the message when before 6 weeks

Answer (score 1):

DateTime will make this simple, something like:-

```
$created_at = new \DateTime("2014-12-01 16:58:23");
$sixWeeks = new \DateInterval('P6W');
if($created_at->add($sixWeeks) < new \DateTime()){
    echo "Six weeks has passed!\n";
} else echo "Not yet!\n";
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/Z90jR)
[Reference](http://php.net/datetime)